# ArcGIS Data Reviewer Regular expression to limit the number of characters (Text Length) in a field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-reviewer, regular-expression

Using ArcGIS Data Reviewer  on top of ArcMap 10.5, I am trying to write a regular expression in table checks that will only allow  5 characters or Less in a field otherwise the value should be reported as an error.

For Example:

abcDe value is ok

abc        value is ok

AB  value is  ok

abcdefg  value is NOT ok

What I have so far looks like this:

```
   \a{0,5}
```

Unfortunately  this is not working (returns all the values in the attribute table) since data reviewer doesn't handle {} "Curly brackets"

What other  options might I have i.e. how do I set a regular expression that returns the unmatched  values if the characters  exceeded a certain length.

---

@ahmadhanb provided Python script that works fine in Field calculator.

But I am looking forward doing this in Data Reviewer R.E as a part of batch checks, unfortunately DR doesn't take  python scripts.

[image]

The Script provided by ahmadhanb:

> ```
> def check(f):
>   import re
>   try:
>     pattern = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-(\w+)-([A-Za-z]
>     [A-Za-z][A-Za-z])")
>     match = pattern.search(f)
>     id = match.group(1)
>     if len(id) <= 8:
>         return "Valid"
>     else:
>         return "Project Name more than 8 Characters"
>   except:
>         return "Project ID Doesn't match the Expression"
> ```

Comment: Why don't you use (Execute SQL check) to check and validate the field length?

Comment: Good point, I didnt because this issue is a part of larger R E check, the main problem is with this part only. I am checking project ID's that looks like "qw-rf-abcde-uyt", the main issue is with this part "abcde" which could be 5 characters  or less in some checks, and 10 or less in some checks, I have included this small part just to make it easier for the community to see where the problem is. Thank you though for you input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new field in the attribute table to check whether the `ID` field has a valid ID or not using regular expression (RE) as follows:

```
def check(f,v):
    import re
    pattern = re.compile(r"\w+-\w+-(\w+)-\w+")
    match = pattern.search(f)
    id = match.group(1)
    if len(id) <= 5:
        return "Valid"
    else:
        return "Invalid"
```

You can use the code above in the new added field using Field Calculator, and it will extract the group(1) - because group(0) means the whole text - which is the portion of the ID that you want to check, and if the number of characters less than or equal to 5 characters, it will return `Valid`, otherwise it will return `Invalid` ID.

Here is the test `ID1` column and the results in the `Check` column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ahmad for the answer, I didnt know that RE can be used in Python, the script worked perfectly and I added some enhancements on it as the following:      def check(f):
  import re
  try:
    pattern = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-(\w+)-([A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z])")
    match = pattern.search(f)
    id = match.group(1)
    if len(id) <= 8:
        return "Valid"
    else:
        return "Project Name more than 8 Characters"
  except:
        return "Project ID Doesn't match the Expression"

Comment: @Ahmadsaleh You are welcome. RE module is one of the powerful modules in python. It is unfortunate that Data Reviewer extension doesn't have python, and I am not sure if anyone can help you to solve your problem as DR extension is not commonly used. Anyway, I hope someone can assist you to find a solution.